# Celery task - Inserting records into database does not work

Tags: django, celery

This is my first days with Celery (Celery 4.1, Python 3, Django 1.10). And I am playing with a simple task that inserts records into my main database. The odd think is that I get no error messages, but the records are just not inserted in the database. Here's the code:

views.py:

```
def test_view(request):
   test.delay()
   return HttpResponse()
```

tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import task
from main.models import EmailDialog

@task()
def test():
    a = EmailDialog()
    a.save()
```

If I remove the `.delay()` and call `test()` as standard python function, I see the records appear in the database. But after adding back the .delay() part, the records are not added. I am wondering what direction to dig.

P.S. I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224076/djando-celery-celery-task-does-not-create-record-in-db), but it did not help solve the issue either.

Comment: Did you start celery?

Comment: Did you start the celery worker?
You should see any errors there. I use this command to check for my errors:
celery -A <proj-name> worker -l info

Answer (score 1):

Please start the celery worker, if not started. Check if all the celery configurations are done as per the doc. And check if the message broker has been provided.